# Best practice to put all API Endpoints list in a file and use in a sapui5 application

Tags: sapui5

I have bunch of API Endpoints as below:

## BaseUrl

```
baseURL=****
```

## create customer

```
createCustomer=api/customer/create
```

## get customer

```
getCustomer=api/customer
```

...and so on

To use them in `controller.js`, I am storing them in `i18n.properties` file(am I doing this correct way?)

and referring as:

```
var url1=this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("baseURL");
url2 = url2+this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("getCustomer");
```

I guess there would be some other file where we would store all API's list as above scenario,

How this is commonly done in a sapui5 application, where these API Endpoints  are stored and are used in controllers or in the application?

A sample example would be great to refer which might store API Endpoints  ,along with how the API's are then called in controller.....

Any help is appreciated TIA!!

Answer (score 1):

I usually like to maintain them in the "manifest.json" file (called also Application Descriptor file for UI5 apps).

There I create an entry inside *dataSources* property of the *sap.app* namespace:

```
    "sap.app": {
        "dataSources": {
            "apiData": {
                "uri": "api/folder/path",
                "uri": "api/folder/path2",
                "uri": "api/folder/path3"
            }
        }
    },
```

In application code, I can retrieve those values by getting the metadata of the component:

```
apiSettings = sap.ui.getCore().getComponent("myAppComponent").getManifestEntry('sap.app').dataSources.apiData
```

A more elegant approach would be to define them in manifest as a dataSource but also in the *sap.ui5* namespace, under *models* property:

```
    "sap.app": {
        "dataSources": {
            "api": {
                "uri": "api.json",
                "type": "REST",
                "settings": { }
            }
        }
    },

    ...

    "sap.ui5": {
       ...
       "models": {
          "api": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "api.json"
          }
       }
       ...
    }
```

This way, UI5 will create a JSON model from a file called **api.json** on application load which you can read by using:

```js
apiSettings = sap.ui.getCore().getComponent("lab").getModel('api').getData()
```

Check this link for more info about Application Descriptor:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da

Comment: This is very informative and thanks for sharing the link mate,  I have come up with some different approach and would like to share the link , Is this a good way to go , please let me know ,  https://www.codepile.net/pile/9YBkJkw2

Comment: For my apps, I like to keep configuration information separated from controller logic as long as possible, since it opens the possibility to reconfigure the application by deploying only the settings files (manifest.json or api.json in my example). But if you think you are not going to need that use case, your approach works too.